# How to get featured image on fetch_feed?

Tags: php, wordpress, rss, feed

I am trying to get the featured image from an RSS feed using fetch_feed on WordPress. But it isn't working. I tried to use: `<?php item->get_thumbnail(); ?>` but it didn't work.

What's the correct way of getting the featured image from an RSS feed? Help is really appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Simple: you can't.

From [the docs](http://simplepie.org/wiki/reference/simplepie/get_image_url): Feeds are allowed to have a "feed logo", which is a single image to represent the feed.

There is no [item-level data](http://simplepie.org/wiki/reference/start#simplepie_item) available for the post thumbnail. Only the feed logo.

Comment: Any changes in this in the last 8 years?

There has to be a way to get `featured-image` from the WordPress RSS feed for posts.